# PHP preg_match find field value

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

This is my example code:

```
$string = "teste aa=11 teste teste";
$var = "aa|bb|cc";
if (preg_match('/^'.$var.'/', $string,$matches)){
        echo "field [$matches[0]], value [$matches[1]]";
```

Output:

```
field [aa],value []
```

I'm trying to output like:

```
field [aa],value[11]
```

I tried several different regexes unsuccessfully. How can I get the value of `aa` with regex?

I'm trying to search multiple strings within a string and pick up their value to be able to change it later.

Comment: this code do the first output

Comment: See [this demo](http://ideone.com/mOkGS7) - does it help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$string = "teste aa=11 teste teste";
$var = "aa|bb|cc";
preg_match('/^.*('.$var.')=(.*?)\s.*/', $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => teste aa=11 teste teste
    [1] => aa
    [2] => 11
)
```

Comment: Nice! Glad to hear it